# Prove that if $η$ is exact, then $η∧β$ is also exact.

Tags: manifolds, products, exterior-algebra

Prove that if $η$ is exact, then $η∧β$ is also exact. 
Please give a clear way to solve?

Comment: Plkease tell what in the world you're talking about...?!

Comment: @DonAntonio From the tags, I believe $\eta$ and $\beta$ are exact differential forms on some differentiable manifold.

Comment: Oh, A.P.:I'm almost certain that's what the OP meant, yet college/university students must be encouraged to stop writing down in a sloppy way and to define whatever they want to talk about...

Comment: @DonAntonio I couldn't agree more, although I fear the OP is somewhat struggling with the language...

Comment: Perhaps you're right, A.P., yet *even* in that case I'd demmand at least some effort to tell what the very question is about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following hint works if you suppose $\beta$ to be closed. I'm not sure (though I doubt) that $\eta \wedge \beta$ is in general exact if $\eta$ is exact.

Try to write out what it means for $\eta$ to be exact, i.e. that $\exists \omega$ such that $\eta=d\omega$. Then recall the formula:
$$
d(\alpha \wedge \gamma)=d\alpha \wedge \gamma + (-1)^k \alpha \wedge d\gamma
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are differential forms and $k$ is the degree of $\alpha$. Now apply it to $\omega\wedge\beta$:
$$
\begin{align*}
d(\omega\wedge\beta)&=d\omega\wedge\beta+(-1)^k\omega\wedge d\beta\\
&=\eta\wedge\beta+(-1)^k\omega\wedge 0\\
&=\eta\wedge\beta
\end{align*}
$$
since $\beta$ closed means that $d\beta=0$. Therefore $\eta\wedge\beta$ is exact.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the hypothesis that $\beta$ is closed is necessary.  In $\mathbb{R}^2$, use $\eta = dx$ and $\beta = y$.  Then $\eta \wedge \beta = ydx$ is not even closed, must less exact.  If the OP finds this too trivial, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, try $\eta = dx$ and $\beta = ydz$.  Then $\eta\wedge \beta$ is again, not closed, so can't be exact.

Comment: @A.P. Yes it is closed. Please can you explain more clear?

Comment: @Mrckh Is this better?

Comment: I will apply his formula for $η∧β$. And then I cannot understand how will I do?  @A.P.

Comment: @Mrckh Sorry, I miswrote. Apply it to $\omega \wedge \beta$.

Comment: Oke. I realized this mistake. I applied. But after the application, what Will I do? @A.P.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have understood. Thank you again:) @a.p